# If a finite group acts freely, then it acts properly discontinuously.

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, finite-groups, group-actions

In my differential geometry course, we saw that a group of diffeomorphism $G$ of a smooth manifold $M$ acts *properly discontiuously* on $M$ if

- each $x \in M$ admits an open neighborhood $U$ such that $\varphi(U) \cap U = \varnothing$ for all $\varphi \in G\backslash \{\text{id}\}$,
- for any pair $x, y \in M$ such that $x$ is not in the orbit of $y$ under $G$, there exists two neighborhoods $U$ and $V$ of $x$ and $y$ respectively such that $\varphi(U) \cap \psi(V) = \varnothing$ for all $\varphi, \psi \in G$.

And then the professor add a remark saying that if a finite group acts freely on $M$, then it also acts properly discontinuously. I really have no idea where to start, does anyone have a hint? Thank you!

Comment: It is just a consequence of being T2 and that the orbit of a discrete group is a discrete set.

Comment: Your definition of "properly discontinuous" is highly non-standard. This is confusing if anyone gives you a definition at odds with all existing literature. What you define here is known as *"free and properly discontinuous"* (or *"free and proper"*, as *"properly discontinuous"* is just a more complicated synonym for *"proper"*).